# Getting gradle error while building android app

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting gradle error while building android app. I am getting following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForNVOLVDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/myjson/stream/MalformedJsonException.class

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

**app/gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.iqvis.nvolv_cleanup"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"

        }


    }

    productFlavors {
        NVOLV {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.nvolv"
            copy {
                from 'src/main/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
            versionCode 51
            versionName "2.0.2"
        }
        ISNA {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.isna"
//            manifest.srcFile "isna/AndroidMenifest.xml"
        }
        ARNOVA {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.arnova"
        }
        PERISCOPE {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.periscope"
        }
        SAN {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.sanjosejazz"
        }
        OHIO {
            applicationId 'com.app.iqvis.ohioaeyc'
            copy {
                from 'src/OHIO/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
            versionCode 32
            versionName '1.992'
        }
        BeckersHealthCare {
            applicationId 'com.app.iqvis.beckershealthcare'
            copy {
                from 'src/BeckersHealthCare/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
            versionCode 32
            versionName '1.91'
        }
        NPCenter {
            applicationId 'com.app.iqvis.npcenter'
            copy {
                from 'src/NPCenter/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
            versionCode 32
            versionName '1.7'
        }
        NVOLVDev {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.nvolvdev"
            copy {
                from 'src/NVOLVDev/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }



            versionCode 19
            versionName "2.39"
        }
        WSCPA {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.wscpa"
            copy {
                from 'src/WSCPA/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
            versionCode 32
            versionName "1.2"
        }
        UMAA {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.umaa"
            copy {
                from 'src/UMAA/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
            versionCode 32
            versionName "1.1"
        }
        SFDW {
            applicationId "com.app.iqvis.sfdw"
            copy {
                from 'src/SFDW/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }

            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.96"

        }
        CALCPA {
            applicationId 'com.app.iqvis.calcpa'
            copy {
                from 'src/CALCPA/'
                include '*.json'
                into '.'
            }
            versionCode 2
            versionName '1.1'
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-volley-master-1.0.15.jar')
    compile files('libs/Branch-1.10.8.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.41.jar')
    compile files('libs/sugar-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-urlshortener-v1-rev22-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v5_3_3_sdkonly.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.41.jar')
//    compile files('libs/nvolvlib.jar')
    provided files('libs/myjson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/iqvisanalytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/stickygridheaders.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/commSinch.jar')
    compile project(':resideMenu')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':nvolvlib')
    compile project(':extensiblepageindicator')
    compile project(':ahbottomnavigation')
    compile project(':commSinch')
    compile project(':fab')
    compile files('libs/gentlyWEB-utils-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/JoSQL-2.2.jar')

//    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'


    compile'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.3@aar'
    compile'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

**nvolvlib gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.43.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.43.jar')
    compile files('libs/myjson-2.3.1.jar')

}
```

Comment: post **build.gradle** file and check any dependency is repeated or not?

Comment: @brahmyadigopula please see the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-volley-master-1.0.15.jar')
        compile files('libs/Branch-1.10.8.jar')
        //    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.41.jar')
        compile files('libs/sugar-1.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar')
        //    compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.6.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-api-services-urlshortener-v1-rev22-1.17.0-rc.jar')
        compile files('libs/crittercism_v5_3_3_sdkonly.jar')
        //    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar')
        //    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.41.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/nvolvlib.jar')
      //  provided files('libs/myjson-2.3.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar')
        compile files('libs/iqvisanalytics.jar')
        compile files('libs/stickygridheaders.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar')
        //    compile files('libs/commSinch.jar')
        compile project(':resideMenu')
        compile project(':library')
        compile project(':nvolvlib')
        compile project(':extensiblepageindicator')
        compile project(':ahbottomnavigation')
        compile project(':commSinch')
        compile project(':fab')
        compile files('libs/gentlyWEB-utils-1.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/JoSQL-2.2.jar')

    //    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'


        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.3@aar'
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
        compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

in nvolvlib grdle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.43.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.43.jar')
    compile files('libs/myjson-2.3.1.jar')

}
```

Comment: what changes did you made in this file? I didn't found any changes.

Comment: did you try it? see  from **'src/NVOLV/'**

Comment: I must have to use this 'src/main/' because i dont have any NVOLV folder. Without this I am unable to build NVOLV flavour.

Comment: I got this error when I import nvolvlib as a module. Please take a look to my app/gradle file

Comment: provided files('libs/myjson-2.3.1.jar') here is the problem this jar name myjson-2.3.1.jar' giving the error